# Android: Unable to resume activity due to NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onresume

Here is my `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        currentMeasurementType = DEFAULT_TYPE;

        final DataBaseHandler handler = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();

        //Spinner for the measurement types
        final Spinner measurementTypesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementTypes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                handler.getMeasurementTypes());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        measurementTypesSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        measurementTypesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Spinner for the measurement sub types
        final Spinner measurementSubTypesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementSubValues);
        try {
            ArrayAdapter<String> subAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    handler.getMeasurementSubType(DEFAULT_TYPE));
            subAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            measurementSubTypesSpinner.setAdapter(subAdapter);
            //measurementSubTypesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); TODO
        } catch(NonExistentMeasurementTypeException ex) {
            Log.d("failed to initialise the spinner for the measurement units", ex.getMessage());
        }

        //the value from which the user is converting from
        EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_value);
        value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                unitValue = charSequence.toString();
                MeasurementType mType =
                        MeasurementType.getMeasurementType(measurementTypesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                String unitName = measurementSubTypesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String unitValue = charSequence.toString();

                //create the converter
                Converter converter = new Converter(mType, unitName, unitValue);
                //convert the values
                ArrayList<Unit> convertedValues = converter.convert();
                //update the list view adapter
                updateUnitAdapter(convertedValues);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                //nothing here
            }
        });

        //ListView
        ListView unitsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.units_list);
        unitsView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        MeasurementType type = handler.getMeasurementType(DEFAULT_TYPE);
        final ArrayList<Unit> unitsConverted = new ArrayList<Unit>();
        unitsConverted.addAll(Arrays.asList(type.getUnits()));
        /**for some reason we need to do a clean up
         * also going to set the unit values to zero
         * for initialisation
         */
        for(Unit u : unitsConverted) {
            if(u == null) {
                unitsConverted.remove(u);
            } else {
                u.setValue(0.00);
            }
        }
        unitAdapter = new UnitListAdapter(this, unitsConverted, type);
        unitsView.setAdapter(unitAdapter);

        Button editList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editList);
        editList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<Unit> units = handler.getUnitsList(currentMeasurementType);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MeasurementTypeListActivity.class);
                i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("units", units);
                i.putExtra("measurementType", currentMeasurementType);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
```

here is my `onResume()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "unitconverter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        DataBaseHandler handler = new DataBaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        //set the spinner for measurement type
        Spinner measurementTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementTypes);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) measurementTypeSpinner.getAdapter();
        int typePos = adapter.getPosition(prefs.getString("currentmeasurementtype", "acceleration"));
        measurementTypeSpinner.setSelection(typePos);

        //set the spinner for the measurement unit
        Spinner measurementUnitSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.MeasurementSubValues);
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) measurementUnitSpinner.getAdapter();
        int unitPos = arrayAdapter.getPosition(prefs.getString("currentmeasurementunit", "centigal"));
        measurementUnitSpinner.setSelection(unitPos);

        //set the value
        EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_value);
        value.setText(prefs.getString("value", "0.00"));

        /**
         * The list view stuff
         */
        ListView unitsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.units_list);
        unitsList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        MeasurementType mType = handler.getMeasurementType(prefs.getString("currentmeasurementtype", "acceleration"));
        //create the converter
        Converter converter = new Converter(MeasurementType.getMeasurementType(prefs.getString("currentmeasurementtype", "acceleration")), prefs.getString("currentmeasurementunit", "centigal"), prefs.getString("value", "0.00"));
        //convert the values
        ArrayList<Unit> convertedValues = converter.convert();

        //update the current adapter
        updateUnitAdapter(convertedValues);
    }
```

here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.UnitConverter/com.example.UnitConverter.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.UnitConverter.MyActivity$1.onTextChanged(MyActivity.java:78)
            at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
            at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
            at com.example.UnitConverter.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:243)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

so it is trying to do this:

```
at com.example.UnitConverter.MyActivity$1.onTextChanged(MyActivity.java:78)
```

after which it goes here:

```
at com.example.UnitConverter.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:243)
```

when I look at line 78 I can see this:

```
String unitName = measurementSubTypesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

so It is trying to set this variable and it looks like it is going to line 242 to do this and line 242 reads this:

```
EditText value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_value);
value.setText(prefs.getString("value", "0.00"));
```

These are actually line 241 and 242, before it is suggested that I haven't initialised the `EditText`. But my thought was that trying to get the String from the preferences was returning null...because it might not have been saved.

Comment: you have to find your all view in onCreate() instead of onResume().

Comment: @HareshChhelana Sorry I didn't understand: "your all view", please could you explain?

Comment: Like you are findViewId() EditText ListView etc in onResume() so try findViewId() EditText ListView etc in onCreate() which first time called when your activity create and onResume() multiple time called when ever you came again activity from another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs for `getSelectedItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()):

> Returns
>   The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.

My guess is that your spinner has nothing selected so you get a NPE when you try to call `toString()` on the returned `null` value. You need to check that you got something back and set a default value if it is `null`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but my questions to this are: 1)what if there is a default value 2)in my onresume I set them measurementTypeSpinner.setSelection(typePos); or does that not really matter because we are talking about onCreate specifically?

Comment: It matters because `onResume` sets text in the `value` view which triggers a call to the `TextWatcher` that was placed on `value` in `onCreate`. The NPE is from the `TextWatcher` callback code, not from `onCreate`. But you probably don't want to be setting a default selection in `onResume`; just do it in `onCreate` and this particular NPE should go away.

Comment: thank you! I have learnt quite a lot from this...I have set them to be whatever is in my sharedpreferences and a default value if they don't have anything, feels like the scope/depth of my program works has changed (in a good way) more user driven rather than me setting default stuff at my whim.